# Selecting data from table to obtain additional distinct columns

Tags: sql, prepared-statement

I have a table with the following columns, staff id, name, earnings. Each staff has five earnings e.g basic salary, rent allowance, utility allowance, transport allowance, risk allowance under earnings column. I want to extract a list to have the following columns, staff id, name, basic salary, rent allowance, utility allowance, transport allowance, risk allowance by using sql.

Comment: This is called a pivot query.  The mechanism differs by database.

Comment: You should show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Post sample data set and the expected result.  Indicate which RDBMs (SQL Flavor) you are using.